# Request Runtime permission React Native

Tags: android, react-native, permissions

I'm trying to ask for runtime permission in ReactNative, but I'm always getting a "Permission is null" error in device screen.

here is the code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Text, View, StyleSheet, TextInput, Button} from 'react-native';
import {PermissionsAndroid} from 'react-native';

export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount()
  {
    PermissionsAndroid.request(PermissionsAndroid.READ_PHONE_STATE) 
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.paragraph}>Seja Bem vindo a BBTS!</Text>
        <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
          Matricula: {this.props.navigation.state.params.matricula}
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
          Email: {this.props.navigation.state.params.email}
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
            imei vem aqui
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I already put this on android manifest. My APi target is 26.

Any ideias?

Solution:

```
async requestPermission() {
    try {
      const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_PHONE_STATE)

      if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
        console.log("You can read the phone state")
      } else {
        console.log("permission denied")
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.warn(err)
    }
  }

  componentDidMount()
  {
    this.requestPermission();
  }
```

Comment: error for await

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `request()` method returns a promise. You'll either need to `async/await` or `.then()/.catch()` and then check `PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED`. That may either fix your problem or help you debug.

Comment: It worked! Thanks the fast response. I'll update the question to help others.

Comment: Great! Glad I could help! If you could accept this answer, that would help me out too ;)

Answer (score 4):

While you do need to handle the promise as @Daniel says the reason for the error is that your permissions request is incorrect, it should be:

> PermissionsAndroid.request(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_PHONE_STATE)

Answer (score 0):

I follow "PermissionsAndroid" bundle in "react-native" folder as

```
 "./node_modules/react-native/Libraries/PermissionsAndroid"
```

Where you can see on all android permission for usage.